# Apps Script: Send email depending one a checkbox selected

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a small laptop rental system in the Google Sheets which sends email depending on checkbox which is selected (checked).

Two emails which are sent are: 1. Approved and 2. Overdue.

Problem that I have with my attempt is that multiple emails are sent even to the users which already have received the approval email when approved checkbox is selected [image]and that no user is receiving any overdue email when overdue checkbox is selected. Also I have a Trigger set up with On edit. Its been wrecking my head for a while now, an help, pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
function onCheckboxEdit(e) {
var source = e.source;
var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var row = range.getRow();
var column = range.getColumn();
console.log("column:: ", column);
    
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 17);
var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
console.log("targetRange:: ", targetValues);
var student = targetValues[0][2];
var recipient = targetValues[0][1];
var checkboxValue = targetValues[0][9];
var checkboxValue2 = targetValues[0][17];    
var subject = ("Laptop Loan Approved");
var body = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nWe are happy to confirm that your laptop loan application has been approved.");
var subject2 = ("Laptop Loan");
var body2 = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nPlease disregard last e-mail sent by us, it was mistakenly sent.");
var subject3 = ("Overdue Laptop Loan");
var body3 = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nThe laptop you have been loaned is due to be returned.");
    
if(column = 10 && checkboxValue == true) {
 console.log("chekbox marked true")
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)    
} else if (column = 10 && checkboxValue == false) {
 console.log("chekbox marked false")
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject2, body2)   
} else {
 console.log("No clue")
} 

if(column = 18 && checkboxValue2 == true) {
 console.log("chekbox marked true")
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject3, body3)
} else if (column = 18 && checkboxValue2 == false) {
 console.log("chekbox marked false")
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject3, body2)    
} else {
 console.log("No clue")
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(column = 10 .........)
```

should be ...

```
if(column == 10 .........)
```

or even ...

```
if(column === 10 .........)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input @JtrM, it worked for the first part but didn't have any effect on the second part (the one that sends overdue emails). Any reason why?

Comment: Have you changed `column = 18` to `column == 18`?

Comment: Hi Emel, yes I did.

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed. Rows and columns are not. `var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 17);` Change the 17 to 18

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much JtrM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JtrM we have an answer!

> rrays are zero indexed. Rows and columns are not. var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 17); Change the 17 to 18 –
> JtrM

> Also adding extra (=) eg: Before column = 10 After column == 10 etc...

```
 function onCheckboxEdit(e) {
    var source = e.source;
    var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();
    console.log("column:: ", column);
        
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 18); // <- 17 changed to 18
    var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
    console.log("targetRange:: ", targetValues);
    var student = targetValues[0][2];
    var recipient = targetValues[0][1];
    var checkboxValue = targetValues[0][9];
    var checkboxValue2 = targetValues[0][17];    
    var subject = ("Laptop Loan Approved");
    var body = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nWe are happy to confirm that your laptop loan application has been approved.");
    var subject2 = ("Laptop Loan");
    var body2 = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nPlease disregard last e-mail sent by us, it was mistakenly sent.");
    var subject3 = ("Overdue Laptop Loan");
    var body3 = ("Hello "+ student +", \n\nThe laptop you have been loaned is due to be returned.");
        
    if(column == 10 && checkboxValue == true) {
     console.log("chekbox marked true")
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)    
    } else if (column == 10 && checkboxValue == false) {
     console.log("chekbox marked false")
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject2, body2)   
    } else if(column == 18 && checkboxValue2 == true) {
     console.log("chekbox marked true")
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject3, body3)
    } else if (column == 18 && checkboxValue2 == false) {
     console.log("chekbox marked false")
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject3, body2)    
    } else {
     console.log("No clue")
    }
}
```